# Can MySQL constrain based on a NULL value combined with an id?

Tags: mysql, django-mptt

I use django-mptt to make a tree structure on a model in a web app.

Unfortunately - once in a while I will get duplicate root nodes in a tree.

These will have NULL as parent_id, and the same tree_id, like this:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+
| id     | parent_id | tree_id |
+--------+-----------+---------+
| 159092 |      NULL |   52098 | 
| 159093 |      NULL |   52098 | 
+--------+-----------+---------+
```

Is there any way to stop this at the database level?
Can I make a constraint in MySQL to avoid getting two or more items with NULL as parent_id and the same tree_id?

Model from models.py with irrelevant fields removed:

```
class Message(MPTTModel):
    # Threaded messages
    text = textmodels.TextField()
```

Comment: Can u show ur models.py file for this table?

Comment: @Rajeev - I have updated my question with the minimal model from models.py.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, but you could create insert and update triggers that will block the new value.  If you are using MySQL >= 5.5 you can use something like this -

```
DELIMITER |

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_msg_insert|

CREATE TRIGGER before_msg_insert BEFORE INSERT ON message
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE xid INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF (NEW.parent_id IS NULL) THEN

        SET xid = (SELECT id FROM message WHERE tree_id = NEW.tree_id AND parent_id IS NULL);

        IF (xid > 0) THEN
            SET @msg = CONCAT("Root node already exists. ID: ", xid);
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END|

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_msg_update|

CREATE TRIGGER before_msg_update BEFORE UPDATE ON message
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE xid INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF (NEW.parent_id IS NULL) THEN

        SET xid = (SELECT id FROM message WHERE tree_id = NEW.tree_id AND id <> NEW.id AND parent_id IS NULL);

        IF (xid > 0) THEN
            SET @msg = CONCAT("Root node already exists. ID: ", xid);
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```